# Command line java programming basics

Tags: java, command-line

Is it possible to edit varargs of main function in java program ?

```
class Program1 {
  public static void main(String args[]){
   int i=44;
   args[i]=34 +"";
   System.out.println(args[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Once you read the chapter on arrays, you should be able to fix your code and run it to find out the answer to your own question.

Comment: Does running the above snippet answer your question? Why or why not?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The lenght of the array is limited to the arguments used.
So if you have 3 arguments (java Program 1st 2nd 3rd) then you will not be able to access more than that (e.g. args[3] for the 4th)

To assign a new value to an existing argument is possible. But I have no idea for what reason to use that.